# If a widget is in a FittedBox, how to set its size to ignore the FittedBox's settings?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `FittedBox` with its setting to `fit: BoxFit.contain`. It has a child of a `CachedNetworkImage` that shows a `CircularProgressIndicator` when the loading is not finished. However the `CircularProgressIndicator` is too big, always streching to the whole screen size, as how the `FittedBox` do its work. I want to make it smaller say 40 * 40, but I tried wrapping it with all kinds of widgets  (`Center`、`SizedBox`, etc.) and failed. So how to set its size to ignore the `FittedBox` settings?

Comment: there is no point using `Image` widget (that scales the content itself) inside `FittedBox`

Comment: You have to use the CircularProgressIndicator outside the FittedBox

Comment: Then how can I change how the `Image` fit its parent? @pskink

Comment: @Rajesh The `CircularProgressIndicator` is the parameter `progressIndicatorBuilder` for `CachedNetworkImage`, so I can't move it outside of the `FittedBox`.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/fit.html

Comment: @pskink Thank you!!! I found that you can also set `fit` for `CachedNetworkImage`, pretty handy.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: url,
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: imageProvider,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                      ))),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                        Icons.error,
                        color: Colors.white30,
                      ))),
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you. As long as we take the `CachedNetworkImage` out of the `FittedBox`, all works well. If it's still wrapped in a `FittedBox`, this way won't work. For a split of time we can see the small `CircularProgressIndicator`, then immediately it's been expanded by the `FittedBox`.

Comment: If you define the fitted box inside the CachedNetworkImage, I think you you would get your desired result

Comment: Actually I got a `FutureBuilder` in a `FittedBox`, and the `FutureBuilder` returns different complex `widget` under different cases. But yeah, I agree with your idea. It sounds like a solid solution.

Comment: Thanks, then put conditions with different widgets. If this helps, kindly check this as an answer. 

Comment: Thank you, but sorry mate, @pskink actually got a better answer. I've given you an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

The full solution to that problem is:

1. Don't use FittedBox outside CachedNetworkImage
2. Use the fit property of CachedNetworkImage with value BoxFit.cover

Example, how to show the CircularProgressIndicator inside a stretched full screen image:

```
 
CachedNetworkImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover, // set fit here
                    imageUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg/800px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg', 
                    
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        const Icon(Icons.error),
                    progressIndicatorBuilder:
                        (context, url, downloadProgress) => Center(
                      child: Stack(children: [
//inside Stack 2 widgets: 1 - CircularProgressIndicator(), 2 - Text(). You can use both or leave one and delete Stack()
                        Center(
//for size control wrap the widget  CircularProgressIndicator in SizedBox
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
// You can use LinearProgressIndicator or CircularProgressIndicator instead

                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              value: downloadProgress.progress,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              strokeWidth: 5,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '${downloadProgress.progress != null ? (((downloadProgress.downloaded.toDouble()) / (downloadProgress.totalSize!.toDouble())) * 100).round() : '...'}%',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
```